# Push Array to Nested Array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I am trying to push an array into another array in Google Apps Script. I am pulling data from a spreadsheet (array of arrays), performing a match relative to another array and then looking to pass the corresponding value from that match into a new array. The new array needs to have the same structure as the original array (array of arrays). I haven't had any luck getting that result. I have tried to 'push' the array of matches but I either get one giant array or an array of smaller arrays that do not match the structure of the original array. When I have tried to use an index based on the loop of the original array I get a 'TypeError'.

```
  /*
    Step 1 - Read All Data Into An Array

  */

  //Gets Client Data For Each Firm
  mysheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNames[1]); //Adjusted worksheet
  ss.setActiveSheet(mysheet);
  arrInput = ss.getRangeByName(rngNameRawClientType).getValues(); 

  //Gets Client Classifcation and Score Data 
  mysheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNames[2]); //Data Validation worksheet
  ss.setActiveSheet(mysheet);
  arrClassification = ss.getRangeByName(rngNameClient).getValues();

  /*

    Step 2 - Perform Calculations on the Data

  */

   //Iterate Through Raw Data Input Array (Rows) 
   for(var r = 0; r < arrInput.length; r++) {

    //Iterate Through Column of Each Row
    for(var c = 0; c < arrInput[r].length; c++) {
       var strClientType = arrInput[r][c];

      //Compare To Classification Array - Return Corresponding Score
      var matchScores = [];
      for(var z = 0; z < arrClassification.length-1; z++) {
        if(arrClassification[z][0] === strClientType) {          
          //Add Score to Scores Array
          matchScores.push(arrClassification[z][1]);       
        }
      }
    }
     scores.push(matchScores);
```

Comment: Could you post examples of both of the arrays and the required output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an empty array between the two for-loops (scoreRow)  and push the value into that array each time you increase c.
Then each time you increase r `scores.push(scoreRow)`.

```
for(var r = 0; r < arrInput.length; r++) {
  var scoreRow = []
  //Iterate Through Column of Each Row
  for(var c = 0; c < arrInput[r].length; c++) {
    var strClientType = arrInput[r][c];

    //Compare To Classification Array - Return Corresponding Score
    var matchScores = [];
    for(var z = 0; z < arrClassification.length-1; z++) {
      if(arrClassification[z][0] === strClientType) {          
        //Add Score to Scores Array
        matchScores.push(arrClassification[z][1]);       
      }
    }
    scoreRow.push(matchScores);
  }
  scores.push(scoreRow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I changed the lookup slightly to run faster. Looping through the classification array was taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const filterData = (data, filters) =>
  data.map((column) => 
    column.filter((row) => 
      !filters.includes(row)))



const inputData = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'b', 'c']
]
const inputFilters = ['b']

const output = filterData(inputData, inputFilters)



console.log(output)
```

I think that is what You are looking for.
It is written in ES6 syntax.

[(Arrow) Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `filterData` takes two arguments, input data and defined filters.

[Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on each iteration returns a new array, as a result of

[Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns new array as a result of

[Array includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) called on `filters`, with `row` as argument

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I am not as familiar with ES6 but this looks pretty clean